# Yeoman update generator error

Tags: node.js, polymer, yeoman

I was trying to update the yeoman generator polymer when I got the following set of errors. I tried updating by going to the Yo menu from the terminal.

```
events.js:74
        throw TypeError('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');
              ^
TypeError: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
    at TypeError (<anonymous>)
    at emit (events.js:74:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/yoyo.js:53:12
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:254:17
    at done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:129:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:251:21
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:575:34)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
```

I cleared the cache and reinstalled the stable version of Node, but I keep getting the error. Any idea what's going wrong?